# XNA studio is not working for my install of Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: xna, game-development, monogame

I can't use XNA studio with my install of Visual Studio 2022, version 17.4.0.

Whenever I try to install XNA game studio 4.0.vsix I get this error

> **XNA Game Studio 4.0**
>
> This extension is not installable on any currently installed
> products.

I installed:

- DirectX
- XNA framework redist
- XNA game studio 4.0 platform tools
- XNA game studio 4.0 shared

and i can't install XNA game studio 4.0.vsix

Fixed I just installed Monogame

Comment: XNA Studio has been pretty dated, as it no longer recieves updates since 2013. I do recommend trying to install Monogame on Visual Studio, which is basically XNA's successor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I suggest using Monogame, but just in case anyone wants the instructions to install XNA:

Download the XNA Game Studio Refresh installer:

[XNAGS40_setup.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27599)

Run it and click through until the error window appears. *Leave it at this window*

Open the File Explorer and Type `%TEMP%` into the address bar.

Order by Date and open the newest folder.

Install each of the following: *Essentially run every exe and msi file in the folder, ignoring errors.*

```
DirectX
XNA framework redist
XNA game studio 4.0 platform tools
XNA game studio 4.0 shared
```

### Now to the meat: Templates

The easiest solution was to copy the templates from an actual install of XNA using VS 2010... This is hard to do now.

I would suggest downloading an existing project and clean it and modify it to your needs.

There are many projects available via a google search, but here is [one](https://www.informit.com/content/images/9780672333453/downloads/0672333457_code.zip) from a [book](https://www.informit.com/store/xna-game-studio-4.0-programming-developing-for-windows-9780672333453).